# How to design my database?

Tags: database

I want to create a database for soccer scores.

Obviously, we have:

- **Countries** (Netherlands, Germany, (But also Europe))
- **Competitions** (Eredivisie, Bundesliga, UEFA Europa League)
- **Teams** (FC Twente, Bayern Munchen, Atletico Madrid)
- **Players** (Luuk de Jong, Manuel Neuer, Tiago Mendes)
- **Matches** (FC Twente - PSV, Bayern - Leverkusen, etc)
- **Events** (Goal scored in 40th minute by Luuk de Jong)

I'm using Dezign in which I have created the scheme below:

[image]

Obviously, a Competition is bound to a Country, a Player to a Team, etc.

But then some problems occur. An Event belongs to a Match and a Player. So the Event could get a `match_id` and a `player_id`. But then any player of any team could 'score' in a match in which he doesn't belong (A player of team C could score in a match between team A and team B). How can I restrict this for example?

Also, a Team could compete in its 'normal' competition, but also in the Champions League. Thus, a simple competition_id in the Team entity would not suffice.

And do you suggest any other thoughts?

***Edit in response to Philipp***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack an entity to express the `Lineup(team, match)` along with a `LineupPosition (lineup, player)`.

You could then associate an `Event` with a `LineupPosition` (specific player in a specific match), thereby linking your `Event` to the correct `Match`, via `LineupPosition`->`Lineup`->`Match`.

Comment: See added image in question, you mean something like that? I can see it indeed will work for the player outside the match scoring problem. But how can I restrict more than two `Lineup`s having the same `match_id`?

Comment: Don't have `match_id` in Lineup, but a `home_lineup_id` and `away_lineup_id` in Match instead. This way you can only have two lineups per Match and you don't loose the home/away information.

Comment: I've edited the image again. Thanks a lot so far, I do have one last question I think. When I create entries in `LineupPosition` I can add players from several teams to the same `lineup_id`. This could come in handy (for example, national teams), but for 'normal' competition matches this should not be possible. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: A bit late, but sorry, no idea how to enforce this on the database level.